# Select rows, columns, and another group of columns based on vector

Tags: select, vector, rstudio, subset

How to select specific rows; specific columns names; and another group of specific columns names based on a vector?

My data:

```
#my data
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Month<-c('Jan','Jan','Mar','Feb','Mar','Jan')
Number<-c(6,5,4,3,2,1)
Color<-c('Red','Red','Blue','Green','Green','Purple')
Q1<-c(0,1,NA,1,0,1)
Q2<-c(1,1,NA,1,NA,1)
Q3<-c(NA,0,0,1,0,1)

mydata<-cbind.data.frame(ID,Month,Number,Color,Q1,Q2,Q3)

#my vector:
Jan.vector<-c('Q1','Q3')
```

I have (mydata):

[image]

1. I want to select the rows where Month is 'Jan'
2. And select column names 'ID' and 'Month'
3. And select column names that are in the vector 'Jan.vector'. I **cannot** list the actual columns names because they will change.
4. I want the resulting rows and columns only, all in one dataset as below:

I want (mydata2):

[image]

(Background: My actual dataset has hundreds of columns, and
and I will need to select columns based on the vector that will change monthly (i.e., Q1, Q3...). The vector will be the only thing that changes. I will not know the question numbers needed and will need to rely on the vector to select the question numbers. The column order will change, as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you correctly:

```
> monthNum <- 1
> wantedCol  <-  c('ID','Month','Color','Q1','Q3') 
> mydata[ mydata$Month==substring(month.name[monthNum],1,3),match(wantedCol,names(mydata))]
  ID Month  Color Q1 Q3
1  1   Jan    Red  0 NA
2  2   Jan    Red  1  0
6  6   Jan Purple  1  1
```

or - you can state the month or months by:

```
> monthName  <-  c('Jan','Mar')
> wantedCol  <-  c('ID','Month','Color','Q1','Q3') 
> mydata[ mydata$Month %in% monthName,match(wantedCol,names(mydata))]
  ID Month  Color Q1 Q3
1  1   Jan    Red  0 NA
2  2   Jan    Red  1  0
3  3   Mar   Blue NA  0
5  5   Mar  Green  0  0
6  6   Jan Purple  1  1
```

or you can state your columns by indexes:

```
> monthName  <-  c('Jan','Mar')
> wantedCol  <-  c(1,2,4,5,7) 
> mydata[ mydata$Month %in% monthName,wantedCol]
  ID Month  Color Q1 Q3
1  1   Jan    Red  0 NA
2  2   Jan    Red  1  0
3  3   Mar   Blue NA  0
5  5   Mar  Green  0  0
6  6   Jan Purple  1  1
```

or if you always want ID,Month and Color :

```
> monthNum <- 1
> wantedColStat  <-  c('ID','Month','Color')
> wantedColDyna  <-  c('Q1','Q3')
> mydata[ mydata$Month==substring(month.name[monthNum],1,3),match(c(wantedColStat,wantedColDyna),names(mydata))]
  ID Month  Color Q1 Q3
1  1   Jan    Red  0 NA
2  2   Jan    Red  1  0
6  6   Jan Purple  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a way to select additional column names that are not in the 'wantedCol' vector? For example, the vector can only include Q1 and Q3 column names. But can I list the other column names (ID, Month, Color) by name? Or, can Q1 and Q3 be in its own vector while, other column names are in a separate vector?